# Using lenses for accessing data inside functors

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I find lenses very useful for accessing deeply nested data, but frequently "containers" like `MVar` or `TVar`s throw off some of the nice properties of lenses.

For example:

```
data SomeStruct = SomeStruct { _b :: Int
                             }
makeLenses ''SomeStruct

data AppState = AppState { _a :: SomeStruct
                         }
makeLenses ''AppState

data App = App { _state :: AppState
               }
makeLenses ''App
```

I can make new lenses using very nice left-to-right composition:

```
let v = App (AppState (SomeStruct 3))
in v^.state.a.b
```

However, if `_state` were of type TVar, the left-to-right composition breaks down, and lenses feel a lot clunkier to use:

```
t <- newTVarIO $ AppState (SomeStruct 3)
let v = App t
atomically $ (^.a.b) <$> readTVar (v^.state)
```

`^.a.b` gets pushed to the left hand side despite `^.state` being the innermost lens.  Is there some way I could deal with these sorts of "container" types and lenses in a more ergonomic way?

Comment: Interesting idea! I did a little Googling and I found [this post from Ed Kmett himself](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2ckwho/comment/cjgx9af) who says that you can’t write to a mutable location without breaking the lens laws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a library (formerly part of [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) proper) called [lens-action](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-action) that helps mixing getters and folds with monading actions without yanking you too much out of the lensy world.

For example, for the type

```
data App = App { _state :: TVar AppState }
```

We could write

```
ghci> :t \v -> v^!state.act readTVar.a.b
\v -> v^!state.act readTVar.a.b :: App -> STM Int
```

The idea is that instead of using the typical view function `(^.)` we use its monadic counterpart [`(^!)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-action-0.2.3/docs/Control-Lens-Action.html#v:-94--33-). And we insert monadic actions using functions like [`act`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-action-0.2.3/docs/Control-Lens-Action.html#v:act) or [`acts`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-action-0.2.3/docs/Control-Lens-Action.html#v:acts). Normal getters and folds don't need to be lifted and composition is still done with plain `(.)`.